# Go back from tabbar to first view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

This is my storyboard
[image: storyboard]
As pointed, i have added a logout button, to reach the first view.

When the app starts it looks like this:
[image: start]
After the login, it goes to a tabbar as shown below:
[image: logout]
I have connected the "Log Out" button with the first view and selected push.  But when i push "Log Out" this is what happens:
[image: error]
I want the login view be shown as it is, but the tabbar appears and also a "Back" button which i wouldn't like it to appear.
*the first 3 tab items have their own navigation controller and the logout button is located on the first tab item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update**
I now understand that the TabBarController is *presented* from the loginController.

The correct way to return is then:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I will leave in the notes below, they assumed we were dealing with a UINavigationController hierarchy. Still worth a read!

---

Here is a partial answer... after I wrote it I realised that your Tab Bar Controller is not a part of your login NavController stack (i don't think anyway), so it won't work - but you should read it anyway to understand why Segue/PUSHing is not the way to go.

I'll update with a more accurate answer for your case later...

You don't want to use a segue, or to PUSH... think of it like a stack of cards, pushing is to add more cards to the stack, so you are adding a version of your login screen to your NavController stack which is contained inside your Tab Bar Controller. This is *not* the same instance of your login screen as you have already created, it is a new instance (*push* makes a new instance).

You want to remove cards from the stack and get back to your first card. That is a POP operation.

One of these will work.

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated

- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

They are `UINavigationController` methods. You can access them from your topmost `UIViewController` like this:

```
[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO;

[self navigationController] popToViewController:myLogInViewController animated:YES;
```

You can trigger them from your logout button by placing an IBAction in the viewController.

It looks as if the viewController you want to return to is indeed your root view controller, so have a go with that and see if it works. If not, you are going to need a reference to the viewController you want to get back to. You could do it by counting the stack. The stack is accessed as the `viewControllers` array property of your Navigation Controller. For example if it is the second viewController up from the rootViewController,

```
UIViewController* logInViewController = 
        [[self navigationController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
```

would get the one you are after.

Comment: i read it and indeed i understood how the thing works. thanks it was really helpful. i will try what you said at the end and let you know.

Comment: If my answer doesn't work, it would help to know how your login screen is connected to your tabBarController. It seems to be a segue - if so is it push, modal or what? If it is code perhaps you could show that code.

Comment: it is a custom segue. Here is the login function:   
 
`-(IBAction)login:(id)sender{  
    NSString *uname = [username text];
    NSString *passwd = [password text];
    
    if (([uname isEqualToString:@"whatever"] || && [passwd isEqualToString:@"whatever"]) {
        
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:self];
    }
  }`

Comment: and the custom segue code:
` -(void)perform
    {  
        UIViewController *dst = [self destinationViewController];
        UIViewController *nav = [self sourceViewController];
        [nav presentViewController:dst animated:YES completion:nil];
        
    }`

Comment: then you won't want pop either... i'll post an update to my reply

Comment: see my update. you need `[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`;

Answer (score 2):

I You r using same navigation for all View Controllers then first find out the Fisrt viewController Object from navigation stack and pop to that view.

for example:

```
-(void)popToSelectedViewController
{
    NSArray *viewC=[self.navigationController viewControllers];

    FirstViewC *firstVC=nil;

    for (int i=0; i<[viewC count]; i++)
    {
        UIViewController *tempVC=[viewC objectAtIndex:i];
        if([tempVC isKindOfClass:[FirstViewC class]])
        {
            firstVC=[viewC objectAtIndex:i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if(firstVC)
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:firstVCanimated:YES];
    else
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

This metod will find ur first VC in navigation stack and pop to that view.

I hope this will helps u.

another ans after edit:

[image: your image]

Pls refer to edited image as N1 and N2 class in ur storyboard. I dont know whatever the name f ur class so i written it as N1 and N2.

In Class N2 add notification :
Write this in your View DidLoad of N2 Class

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(popToRooToview) name:@"PopView" object:nil];


   //other stuffs
}
```

and define the notification selector as:

```
-(void)popToRooToview
{

  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

remove notification observer in viewDidUnLoad

```
-(void)viewDidUnload
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"PopView" object:nil];
}
```

and Now in ur N1 class  on click of Logout Btn call this method:

```
 -(void)logoutButtonClicked
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PopView" object:nil];

}
```

//remember the notification name "PopView" is same for the notification in class N1 and post notification for class in N2

Comment: i think they are different navigation controllers.
on the action of the logout button (inside tabbar) i did nslog("%d",[[[self navigationController] viewControllers] count]); and it returned 1

Comment: ok i understand ur problem. there is a solution for this:
Add notification in ur tabbar main class  and when u click on logout button from where u want to pop call post notification of tabbar class. it sends u a call on this class and pop all views from there.

If u r not clear i will provide u a sample of this concept

Comment: yes please, i am new to cocoa touch and an example would be appreciated.

Comment: can u provide a large image of ur storyboard. its not clear in image

Comment: i updated the storyboard with a bigger one, i hope its clearer.

Comment: I have edited my ans pls refer to that and check whether ur problem is solved or not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22643/discussion-between-satish-k-azad-and-ozmax)